# Using a method from one class inside the other class method.

Tags: java

So, I got two classes.

```
public class Team {    
private String teamName;    

public Team(String team){
    this.teamName = team;
}    

public void addPlayer(String name, String goalAmount){

}

public void addPlayer(String goalAmount){

}
}
```

and

```
public class Player {
private String playerName;
private int goals = 0;

public Player(String name, int goals){
    this.playerName = name;
    this.goals = goals;
}    

public Player(String name){
    this.playerName = name;
}     

}
```

How can I use `public Player(String name, int goals)` or `public Player(String name)` inside Team class. I created two methods for both but don't know what should I write in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Player class' methods you are pointing to are not methods, they are overloaded `constructors` of the class. So if you want to create (or instantiate) a Player from the Team class' addPlayer(..) method, you can instantiate a new Player like this (in the corresponding methods of the Team class):

```
public void addPlayer(String name, String goalAmount) {
  Player player = new Player(name, goalAmount);
}

public void addPlayer(String name) {
  Player player = new Player(name);
}
```

The question is, where do you store these objects? I imagine your Team needs a List of Players. So you add to the Team class:

```
private List<Player> players;
```

Then, in the above methods, you can add the line:

```
this.players.add(player);
```

Comment: should explain to him how to loop trough the objects as well! haha. but well explained! should have everything he needs

Comment: Yea I know how to loop through. Just staring to learn everything about classes and can't understand all.
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @UkoMelis you should pick up for a Java fundamentals book which can explain things to you way better than a narrowly scoped answer to your question. Try to limit your questions on StackOverflow to issues or challenges you are not able to overcome even after referring to standard text/books.

Answer (score 1):

First, put more effort into this - it looks like a homework question. Second, you need to import the Player class into the Team class. Then in Team class you will have access to the functionality exposed by the Player class.